# Get Selector Value Within Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get selector value in a change event?

I have tried this:

```
    $("#frek_menonton_tv :input").change(function(){
        $(this).selector;
    });
```

and returning an empty string.

Desired result:

`frek_menonton_tv :input` not the `Object`

Comment: `$(this)` will give you instance of `input` whose value is changed.

Comment: what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.selector` you are looking for, has been deprecated from version 1.7

See [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/selector/)

> The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting .live() in the jQuery Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version. The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set. Plugins that need to use a selector should have the caller pass in the selector as part of the plugin's arguments during initialization.

Since you can get the selector like this:

```
   var obj = $("#frek_menonton_tv :input");
    alert(obj.selector);
```

So you can do a hack to wrap your event binding to another function and use that for all event bindings. As can add any data to the event bound to an control during binding using the overload for `.on()` , use the selctor from the context inside the subscribe function and bind it to the event data.

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

```
$.fn.subscribeEvent = function(eventType, callBack) {
    this.on(eventType, {'selector': this.selector}, callBack);
   //Older versions of jquery you can use bind
   //this.bind(eventType, {'selector': this.selector}, callBack);

};

$(function() {

   $("#frek_menonton_tv :input").subscribeEvent('change', function(e){
      alert(e.data.selector);
   });

});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9cAb/)

Comment: Any alternative solutions?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis what are you trying to achieve? Use case?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis Added a possible option see if that is possible.

Comment: All right, i'm use 1.5.2 version of jQuery, i'll use your previous solution (the funny solution). +1 for deprecated information.

Comment: @WildanMuhlis Older versions of jquery you can use `this.bind(eventType, {'selector': this.selector}, callBack);
` see my update.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` will give instance of `input`

```
 $("#frek_menonton_tv :input").change(function(){
        console.log($(this));
    });
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

just use `$(this)`

```
$("#frek_menonton_tv :input").change(function(){
        console.log( $(this) );// will show Object Input
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question